# How to read Data.gov Data Update Frequency code

Tags: data.gov

How to read data update frequency code. For example for [Consumer Complaint Database](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/consumer-complaint-database) the code in the Dates section is :

Data Update Frequency:  **R/P1D**

How to read **R/P1D**. I guess it is a daily update but I am not sure. Where can I find the codification rule?

Comment: https://project-open-data.cio.gov/iso8601_guidance/ may or may not be helpful.